# Were to find device information about their rated processing use limitations

Tags: power, android

I'm an engineer working with device drivers+firmware. Have no much knowledge about the mobile device processing walls and hardware and limitations.

I have to do some engineering testing with commercial devices like google pixel, which tests would last for days continuously and may use the devices processing power completely ( huge image processing task). What I want to know is an information source where I can predict their processing power rated limitations, and I need a formal method derive it from processor specification when manufacture does not share such information. Yes we are pushing the device processing power to it's limits.

- What information/specs should I collect?
- Any formal method to decide their processing limits so less number of devices will be bricked during the engineering testing.
- Any information on benchmarking/monitoring tools that I could use. For a example when I hitting the device limits that wold automatically abort the test or shutdown the device.

Comment: What do you mean with "processing power" in this context? It is a little unclear, at least to me. If you want a formal method to derive something, you need to formally define something.

Comment: @VladimirCravero , we are developing software which may push the processor to their limits. When doing so we may be exceeding the rated use. That rated use was not formally mentioned by the OEM manufacture. When we are developing for android, we have a large device matrix. Need to conduct our engineering testing without exceeding devices rated use of processing power.

Comment: As Vladimir said, what exactly do you mean by 'processing power'? You will be exceeding the rated use of what *exactly*? If you are asking for information that was not specified by the manufacturer, it may be best to ask them.

Comment: oky let's say using processing cycles per second. Where I can also read that value on android easily as well.